# Get own Service Principal Name in an Azure DevOps Powershell pipeline task

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, pipeline

When running an Azure Powershell task in an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline  with system.debug=true, you will get an output similar to this:

```
# anonymized
...
2019-09-05T12:19:41.8983585Z ##[debug]INPUT_CONNECTEDSERVICENAMEARM: '7dd40b2a-1c37-4c0a-803e-9b0044a8b54e'
2019-09-05T12:19:41.9156487Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_URL_7dd40b2a-1c37-4c0a-803e-9b0044a8b54e: 'https://management.azure.com/'
2019-09-05T12:19:41.9188051Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_AUTH_7dd40b2a-1c37-4c0a-803e-9b0044a8b54e: '********'
2019-09-05T12:19:41.9221892Z ##[debug]ENDPOINT_DATA_7dd40b2a-1c37-4c0a-803e-9b0044a8b54e: '{"subscriptionId":"b855f753-d5b3-48f4-b7cd-5beb58fb5508","subscriptionName":"Entenhausen","environment":"AzureCloud","creationMode":"Automatic","azureSpnRoleAssignmentId":"5ddcc3fe-f93c-4771-8041-50b49f76b828","azureSpnPermissions":"[{\"roleAssignmentId\":\"5ddcc3fe-f93c-4771-8041-50b49f76b828\",\"resourceProvider\":\"Microsoft.RoleAssignment\",\"provisioned\":true}]","spnObjectId":"76055cb6-3b75-4191-9309-306b32dad443","appObjectId":"e4b90b9d-7a73-42a3-ae6e-4daec910def4","environmentUrl":"https://management.azure.com/","galleryUrl":"https://gallery.azure.com/","serviceManagementUrl":"https://management.core.windows.net/","resourceManagerUrl":"https://management.azure.com/","activeDirectoryAuthority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/","environmentAuthorityUrl":"https://login.windows.net/","graphUrl":"https://graph.windows.net/","managementPortalUrl":"https://manage.windowsazure.com/","armManagementPortalUrl":"https://portal.azure.com/","activeDirectoryServiceEndpointResourceId":"https://management.core.windows.net/","sqlDatabaseDnsSuffix":".database.windows.net","AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix":"vault.azure.net","AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId":"https://vault.azure.net","StorageEndpointSuffix":"core.windows.net","EnableAdfsAuthentication":"false"}'
2019-09-05T12:19:41.9284444Z ##[debug]AuthScheme ServicePrincipal
...
```

I need to add the SPN of the Azure DevOps connection to a resource. When changing subscriptions or pipelines, the SPN also changes and I do not want to hardcode the value.
As the value is printed in the system.debug=true output, I am wondering how to access my own SPN within a pipeline task. Is it possible to read out `spnObjectId":"76055cb6-3b75-4191-9309-306b32dad443"` somehow using Powershell?

Answer (score 7):

Information about the Service Principal can be accessed using Get-AzureRmContext but the information is limited and some is obfuscated in the logs so you need to make a second call to Get-AzureRmServicePrincipal to access the ObjectId

```
$Context = Get-AzureRmContext
$AzureDevOpsServicePrincipal = Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $Context.Account.Id
$ObjectId = $AzureDevOpsServicePrincipal.Id
```

The Id exposed in `$Context.Account.Id` is the Service Principals ApplicationId

Answer (score -1):

SPN within a pipeline task is nothing but the Azure subscription you have passed on to the task. You can click on manage connections and copy the details of the SPN under connections and use them as you need. But, I am not sure why do you want to use the SPN directly as you can always use an Azure Powershell Task and just select the subscription. Once you store the Connection, you can always reuse it in different pipelines.

[image]

Comment: e.g. the subscription connection is able to create a keyvault but you have to add the spn to it so that you can also create secrets in the keyvault from the same pipeline run. When you deploy in multiple stages to multiple subscriptions, the subscription connection changes. Also when other users copy a pipeline as a template for further modifications, they might add their own connection and therefore I would like to read the spn from within the execution context.